# Installing python-mysql on windows with AppServ

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, windows-7, python, windows-registry

I am trying to install the python module "mysql" on Windows 7 with apache installed with AppServ (installation includes Apache, MySQL and PHP).

When I try to run the setup.py script of "python-mysql" I get error

```
serverKey = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, options['registry_key'])
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

The problem is that it can not find the registry of MySQL. So I opened `regedit` and looked under the default location (which was specified in setup.py) - `SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL` Server 5.1 under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

However, I found that this location does not exist on my computer, and after searching a bit I found that under `HKEY_USERS` I do have "AppServ" under `SOFTWARE`, but `MySQL Server` is no where to be found!

Anyone had any experience with this issue and knows where I should point the config?

Thanks!
Joel

Answer (score 1):

I added it manually and entered to String values for "Version" and "Location" (which I mapped to the bin folder of my MySQL installation path). Then you need to update site.cfg with the same key value you added those strings under in your registry. That should work barring other issues. Mine did not compile due to Python being compiled with Visual Studio... grrr. Hope this helps you though!